# How would I join 4 subqueries with a union in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, union

So I'm trying to join 4 subqueries with a Union in MySQL and I can't figure it out.

Below are the 4 subqueries. I need to union the first 2 with the last 2.

when I try to UNION the 4 I get a syntax error. Do I need to change the code for the subqueries?

> ```
>   SELECT Title, AlbumDescription FROM Albums WHERE
>   MATCH(AlbumDescription)                            
>   AGAINST('blondes');
>
>   SELECT Title, AlbumDescription FROM Albums WHERE MATCH(AlbumDescription)                                        
>   AGAINST('bodybags'); 
>
>   SELECT Title, AlbumDescription FROM Albums WHERE MATCH(AlbumDescrption)                             
>   AGAINST('fireplaces' WITH QUERY EXPANSION);     
>
>   SELECT Title, AlbumDescription FROM Albums WHERE MATCH(AlbumDescription)                                        
>   AGAINST('sighing' WITH QUERY EXPANSION);
> ```
>
> > ```
> > SELECT Title, AlbumDescription FROM Albums  WHERE
> > MATCH(AlbumDescription)  
> >   AGAINST('blondes') 
> >
> > SELECT Title, AlbumDescription FROM Albums  WHERE
> > MATCH(AlbumDescription)  
> >   AGAINST('bodybags')
> >
> > UNION
> >
> > SELECT Title, AlbumDescription FROM Albums  WHERE
> > MATCH(AlbumDescription)  
> >   AGAINST('fireplaces' WITH QUERY EXPANSION) 
> >
> > SELECT Title, AlbumDescription FROM Albums  WHERE
> > MATCH(AlbumDescription)  
> >   AGAINST('sighing' WITH QUERY EXPANSION);
> > ```

I used the syntax above and I am getting an error saying I have a syntax error near line 3. For some reason there are indents where AGAINST is in the syntax on here, but it is not in my actual code.

Comment: If you already know that UNION exists, then what’s the actual question here?

Comment: This is just a chain of logical `OR`, no?  `WHERE MATCH(AlbumDescription) AGAINST ('blondes') OR MATCH(AlbumDescription) AGAINST('bodybags')...`

Comment: Well, I'm trying to UNION them, and it's not working. When I use UNION between the 4 i get a syntax error. So, I'm not really sure if I need to change the syntax on the subqueries or not.

Comment: The `UNION` will work between them if you remove the `;` delimiters.

Comment: You can also combine the first two with `+` assuming a boolean match `WHERE MATCH(AlbumDescription) AGAINST ('blondes bodybags')`

Comment: I can't do that unfortunately, the assignment specifically says it has to be 4 subqueries 2 without WITH QUERY EXPANSION and 2 with it. Which I think is dumb, I initially going to the way you suggested.

Comment: To use subselects you need to formulate complete select statements:  `SELECT (SELECT....), (SELECT...) UNION SELECT (SELECT...), (SELECT...)` Subselects would need to be comma-separated in the parent `SELECT` list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you need to use UNION?

The queries are all against the same table; do it as a single SELECT against the table. Use `AND` and/or `OR` logical operators to combine the predicates.

To get rows from the table that satisfy any of the conditions:

```
SELECT a.Title
     , a.AlbumDescription
  FROM Albums a 
 WHERE MATCH(a.AlbumDescription) AGAINST('blondes') 
    OR MATCH(a.AlbumDescription) AGAINST('bodybags')
    OR MATCH(a.AlbumDescription) AGAINST('fireplaces' WITH QUERY EXPANSION)
    OR MATCH(a.AlbumDescription) AGAINST('sighing' WITH QUERY EXPANSION)
```

---

Here's an example of the `UNION` set operator to combine the results from four queries:

```
SELECT a.Title
     , a.AlbumDescription
  FROM Albums a 
 WHERE MATCH(a.AlbumDescription) AGAINST('blondes') 
 UNION
SELECT a.Title
     , a.AlbumDescription
  FROM Albums a 
 WHERE MATCH(a.AlbumDescription) AGAINST('bodybags')
 UNION
SELECT a.Title
     , a.AlbumDescription
  FROM Albums a 
 WHERE MATCH(a.AlbumDescription) AGAINST('sighing' WITH QUERY EXPANSION)
 UNION
SELECT a.Title
     , a.AlbumDescription
  FROM Albums a 
 WHERE MATCH(a.AlbumDescription) AGAINST('sighing' WITH QUERY EXPANSION)
```